# Flashlight (LED BACK) on/off, camera null HTC

Tags: android, null, camera, flashlight

I'm practicing and trying to change the flashlight (torch) on the back of my HTC.
But I get no camera access, I put in the manifest the following:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
>    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
>    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
>  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
> ```

It can be very simple and stupid, but google and StackOverflow didn't gave me a solution, so can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?
This is my activity file:

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.hardware.Camera; 
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.*; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.util.Log; 
import java.util.List;

public class FlashlightActivity extends Activity {      
  private Camera mCamera;

  /** Called when the activity is first created, just a titlescreen. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageButton titlescreen = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.titlescreen);
    titlescreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
      public void onClick(View v){
        TurnFlashOff();
        if (mCamera==null){ 
          finish();}
        else {
          Intent go = new Intent(TurnMeOnFlashlightActivity.this,TMO_App.class);
          startActivity(go);
        }
      }
    });
    Log.d("TurnMeOn", "startpage");
  }

  private void TurnFlashOff(){
    if(mCamera != null){
      mCamera = Camera.open();
      Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
      List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();

      if (flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(params); 
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(TurnMeOnFlashlightActivity.this, R.string.FlashNoSupport, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
      } 
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(TurnMeOnFlashlightActivity.this, R.string.FlashNoSupport, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Found it! The Camera wasn't released in another activity